# How to access/delete a folder accidentally named with escaped characters?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

I was setting up a cloud server and saw that I accidentally added a folder named `^[[4~` (with escape code). I want to see what is inside and if that was just a mistake then remove that directory. However I cannot `cd` nor `ls` the contents. I tried finding out the escape code so that I could enter a command like `cd \x1b[30m;` and hope that it would get me in the directory.

What if I was to `cd` or remove by searching for the first directory listed with `ls`. Would that be possible? Because when I do a `ls |grep 4` two results come up and one of them is the one I'm trying to access.

Either finding out the folder name in escape string or changing the directory to the first directory `ls` finds might be a solution here. How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A funny way to deal with that, using Bash: `cd` into the directory (that's easy).

Then we'll check that a control character is in the file's name: if you issue

```
printf 'strange: %s\n' *[[:cntrl:]]*
```

you should see your file there. If not, try to use another character class or modify the glob so that it matches your file name. (But very likely, you'll only have the bizarre one.) Then, three possiblities:

- The previous command only issued your bizarre file. Then, easy, just rename it:

  ```
  mv -nv *[[:cntrl:]]* a_less_bizarre_name
  ```

  done!
- The previous command issued several filenames with bizarre names. Then, rename them all as:

  ```
  i=0
  for biz in *[[:cntrl:]]*; do
      mv -nv "$biz" a_less_bizarre_name$((++i))
  done
  ```

  done!
- The previous command output several names, but you only want to change one. In this case, we'll put them all in an array, print them all out with a number in front, and then we'll select only the one we want:

  ```
  bizarre=( *[[:cntrl:]]* )
  for index in "${!bizarre[@]}"; do
      printf "%s --> %s\n" "$index" "${bizarre[index]}"
  done
  # Then, look at the index of the one you want to rename
  # If its index is 42, issue:
  mv -nv "${bizarre[42]}" a_less_bizarre_name
  ```

  done!

**Note.** If you use these commands, make sure you use them with the proper quotings (i.e., the quotings I gave). Do not alter the quotings!

*Remark.* You will very likely want first to issue the `mv` I gave with an `echo` in front, just to see what it'll do, e.g.,

```
echo mv -nv *[[:cntrl:]]* a_less_bizarre_name
```

and remove the `echo` when you're happy with it! Anyways, I'm using the `-n` switch so as to not overwrite an otherwise existing file. All these commands are rather safe if you use them as I typed them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Find out what the directory is named as escaped:

   ```
   $ ls -b
   # \033[4~
   ```
2. Remove by:

   ```
   rmdir -v `echo -e "\033[4~"`
   ```

Comment: This is clunky and won't work (option `-e` for `rmdir` is invalid – and anyways, you don't want to remove a directory called `echo` if such a directory exists!). Maybe you mean `rmdir -v $'\033[4~'` instead. But the OP would like to check if it's safe to remove the directory (e.g., `cd` in there and list its files...).

Comment: oh sorry, there are actually \` around echo (markdown formatted it, correcting...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works for special chars too, but it's worth giving it a try. Try running

```
ls -d */ | grep -n "" | more
```

in the parent folder; this prints all its directories preceded by a number and the colon `:` (something like `1:folder1` `2:folder2` ...). Find the number corresponding to your folder and then run the following line (replace `${num}` with the number)

```
cd $(ls -d */ | grep -n "" | grep "^${num}:" | cut -d: -f2)
```

or maybe with quotes:

```
cd "$(ls -d */ | grep -n '' | grep ^${num}: | cut -d: -f2)"
```

- `ls -d */` lists all the directories
- `grep -n ""` matches all the lines containing `""`, i.e. every one, and option `-n` enumerates each one
- `grep "^${num}:"` prints only the `${num}`-th line
- since the line is something like `LineNumber:FolderName`, `cut -d: -f2` picks only `FolderName`
- `ls $( ..command.. )` uses the output of `..command..` as argument of `ls`

Answer (score -1):

Try using quotes.

`cd "\x1b[30m;"`

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what exactly the escape code looks like. How can I find out what the ESC code would be for that folder?

Comment: I actually found it by entering `ls -b` command. The folder name looks like `\033[4~` now.